# MS Graph - Cannot remove license from user, error says license is inherited from group, but user is not in group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a user who was removed from a group yesterday. The group has an A3 license assigned. But the user still shows in Entra as having the license, even though she has been removed from the group.

[image]

User is not in the group shown - she was in the group but I removed her yesterday:

[image]

When I try to remove the A3 license from this user using the following code, I receive an error:

```
$uri = '/users/{0}/assignLicense' -f $userId
$licenseUpdatePayload = @{
    addLicenses     = @()
    removeLicenses  = @( $A3LicenseSku )
}
Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $licenseUpdatePayload
```

The error:

```
Invoke-MgGraphRequest: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<#######>/assignLicense HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Cache-Control: no-cache Tr
ansfer-Encoding:
chunked Vary: Accept-Encoding Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 request-id: <#######> client-request-id:
<#######> x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"<#######>","Slice":"E","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"<#######>"}} x-ms-resource-unit: 1 Date: Mon, 20 Nov 2023 20:51:01 GMT Content-Type:
application/json Content-Encoding: gzip  {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"User license is inherited from a group membership and it cannot be removed
directly from the
user.","innerError":{"date":"2023-11-20T20:51:01","request-id":"<#######>","client-request-id":"<#######>"}}}
```

I would be very grateful for any help with this. Thank you.

Comment: Note that, licenses that a user inherits from a group cannot be removed directly via `/users` API. In your case, try reprocessing the group by going to the groups pane, open Licenses, and then select the **`Reprocess`** button on the toolbar. Refer these [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/licensing-groups-resolve-problems#force-group-license-processing-to-resolve-errors) and [link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7244cc59-c82c-4312-983b-9deadec7e3b1/removed-group-based-license-assignment-user-stuck-with-orpaned-inheritance?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

Comment: Thanks very much @Sridevi - this is useful information. The licensing problem for this particular user seems to have resolved, but we do occasionally have problems which this information will be very helpful for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> As I mentioned in comments, licenses that a user inherits from a group
> **cannot** be removed directly via `/users` API.

I have one user with license **inherited** from Azure AD group like below:

[image]

When I ran your PowerShell script in my environment, I too got **same error**:

```
$userId = "userId"
$LicenseSku = "license_skuId"
$uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}/assignLicense' -f $userId
$licenseUpdatePayload = @{
    addLicenses     = @()
    removeLicenses  = @( $LicenseSku )
}
Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $licenseUpdatePayload
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you can run below PowerShell script to **remove** the user from license-assigned group:

```
$groupId = "groupId"
$userId = "userId"
$uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{0}/members/{1}/$ref' -f $groupId,$userId

Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method DELETE
```

When I checked the same in Portal after few minutes, license **removed** successfully from user like this:

[image]

If error still persists, try **reprocessing** the license of group or user as mentioned in this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/licensing-groups-resolve-problems#force-group-license-processing-to-resolve-errors):

*Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Groups -> Select Group -> Licenses -> Click on Reprocess button*

[image]